# Oracle SQL Developer - Incomplete Result Set when Copy/Pasting

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, oracle-database

I have noticed on several occasions when trying to Select All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) all of the records in the result set or table data, and then Copying (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and Pasting into Excel, that some of the records are missing.

**For example:**
Performing a record count on a table shows: 1600 records

Select All, Copy/Paste: Only 1570 records.
What is going on here?

Comment: This sounds like the same question, does the answer posted here help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024574/inaccurate-count-in-oracle-sql-developer